# Discord.py breaking out of a loop with a given custom command. Python 3.9.2

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@client.command(name="start")
async def start(maid_cafe):
    x = len(images)
    if x == 0:
        await maid_cafe.send("0 images cached,\nTry !cache first.")
        return

    loop_run = 1;
    while loop_run < 60:
        if not halt:
            image = random.choice(images)
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            maid_cafe = client.get_channel(773213667801169930)
            await maid_cafe.send(file=discord.File(f"{image}"))
        else:
            break
```

Need some help here sorta struggling with loops on python.

The problem over here is described as follows. I've defined halt as a global at the top of my code

```py
# Misc.
global halt
global images
images = []
halt = True
```

I have another function where if I trigger the entire loop breaks this is right below the function which I listed first here

```py
@client.command(name="halt")
async def halt(ctx):
    halt = True
    await ctx.send("Send loop coming to a stop.")
```

Now when I execute a certain phrase for the function to execute it displays nothing on my discord channel nor prints out any errors on the run window. But when I remove

```py
if not halt:
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ...
        else:
            break
```

The bot displays the message on the channel perfectly with no issues but with a cost that I can't stop the loop and it keeps going on continuously...

Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is if it is possible to create a separate function just to break out of a loop.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That's not how the keyword `global` works in Python!** In Python, it means "do not look up this variable in the local scope but look in the global scope instead", meaning you have to use the global keyword *inside* of your function. (What your code currently does is create a new local variable called `halt` which does not interact with the global `halt`).

Try to make your code look like this:

```py
halt = False


@client.command(name="start")
async def start(maid_cafe):
    global halt  # !!!!!!!!! IMPORTANT !!!!!!!!!
    halt = False

    loop_run = 1
    while loop_run < 60:
        if not halt:  # no "global" needed for reads, only for write
            ...


@client.command(name="halt")
async def halt(ctx):
    global halt  # !!!!!!!!! IMPORTANT !!!!!!!!!
    halt = True

    await ctx.send("Send loop coming to a stop.")
```

Comment: Just had a look with my code and corrected the mistakes but it looks like there's no luck yet I've removed the previous `global halt` at the top and replaced it inside the function, mentioned `halt=True` at top of the start function and edited everything inside the start function as you mentioned but still don't understand what's preventing it from running...

Comment: I fixed the stopping mechanism. To get it to start running just put `halt = False` on the top-level (my fault)

Comment: No luck either with `halt = False` should I just submit in my full code just to see if it might be conflicting with something? I very much doubt that it's conflicting outside since it works perfectly fine when I remove the `if not halt:` statement along with `else: break`

Comment: @AzurBarnitzke sure, submit it

Comment: Oh found out something it looks like when I include 'halt = False' in-between 'return' and 'loop_run = 1' the bot finally starts pushing out images and I receive the desired output problem is that when I execute '!halt!' which I corrected earlier it does not seem to have any effect on the bot...? I'll submit the code just give me a minute or so.

Comment: @AzurBarnitzke You will have to add `global halt` at the start of both functions I suspect. Let me update my answer

Comment: Yep, it works flawlessly now! Thanks a-lot!

Comment: No problem, it was my fault for getting it wrong at first

Answer (score 0):

The base of your problem is that `halt` is set to `True` on startup.

Also here are some other things I found about your code:

- The halt funcion/command does nothing. I asume you would like it to set `halt` to `True` and then to `False` afterwards.
- With this method if the bot runs on more than one place, the halt command would end all of them. I dont know if thats what you want.
- Your code would be more readeble if you swtich this

```py
while loop_run < 60:
    if not halt:
        ...
    else:
       break
```

With this:

```py
while loop_run < 60 and not halt:
    ...
```

- `loop_run` is never incremented.

Comment: I've changed it to 

`while loop_run < 60 and not halt:`

Removed 

```else: break```

Tried setting at the top of the code `halt = True` and then later `halt = False` just for checking but
still no output from the bot.

Also yes I've already acknowledged that if I use the bot in more than one place a single call-out can bring the whole bot down but as of now I have no plans of doing so. Thanks for reminding me. Would be nice if you could figure out what could still be the issue...